# Is comparison of function-pointers legal

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I want to know whether comparing (not only `==` and `!=`) function-pointers is legal if both functions have the same type or are cast to `void*`.

Here some example code:

```
    #include <iostream>
    struct A { static void f(){} };
    struct B { static void f(){} };
    int main()
    {
        std::cout << reinterpret_cast<void*>(&A::f) << '\n';
        std::cout << reinterpret_cast<void*>(&B::f) << '\n';
        std::cout << (&A::f < &B::f) << '\n';
    }
```

GCC (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c03b2d2dc528c197) and Clang (http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3330f8e0b88cc523) seem to be fine with it.

Can someone point me at the right passage in the standard?

Thanks!

Comment: Instead of casting to void, you could also try casting both to void function pointers (i.e.: the same function pointer type).  I.e.: `(void (*)(void *))foo`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your example may fail to compile. If it does compile, this is not guaranteed to work as expected. In practice though, it likely will.

As of C++11, conversion of function pointers to object pointers is conditionally-supported with implementation-defined results. Conditionally-supported means implementations can choose whether they want to support it. If they don't, they may just issue an error message.

For implementations that do support it, very little is guaranteed about the result of the conversion: all that's said is that if it's supported, you can convert it back and get the original value. This doesn't imply anything about the results of equality or relational comparisons.

[[expr.reinterpret.cast]p8](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.reinterpret.cast):

> 8 Converting a function pointer to an object pointer type or vice versa is conditionally-supported. The meaning of such a conversion is implementation-defined, except that if an implementation supports conversions in both directions, converting a prvalue of one type to the other type and back, possibly with different cv-qualification, shall yield the original pointer value.

For meaningful `==` and `!=` comparisons, just compare directly.

[[expr.eq]p3](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.eq):

> [...]
>
> (3.2) Otherwise, if the pointers are both null, both point to the same function, or both represent the same address, they compare equal.
> (3.3) Otherwise, the pointers compare unequal.

As for `<`, the usual rules for `<` render your comparison just as meaningless as `int i, j; &i < &j;`:

[[expr.rel]p4](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.rel):

> 4 The result of comparing unequal pointers to objects<sup>86</sup> is defined in terms of a partial order consistent with the following rules:
>
> [...]
>
> (4.3) Otherwise, neither pointer is required to compare greater than the other.